# How do I get two side by side table Div containers the same height

Tags: html, css, html-table, containers

I have two Div containers side by side, but one is shorter than the other. I would like both table borders to equal the same height as the larger of the two.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-right:-5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other on screens that are smaller than 600 px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<table style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="column">
<table style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flex to the row container, then the columns will strech vertically.

```css
.row {
   ...
   display: flex;
}

table {
   ...
   height: 100%; // To fill .column container
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adjusting some of your code:
In your :

```
 .row {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

 .column {
     width: 100%;
     background: white;
     color: grey;
     margin: 0 .5em;
     padding: .5em; 
  }
   table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
     min-height: 100%;
     /* width: 100%; */
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .column {
    flex: 1;

  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .row{
      flex-direction: column
    }
    .column {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
      sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
      nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
      sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must transition `class="column"` than `<div>` to in two `<table>` and change their name to `class="column1"` and `class="column2"`.

Now we must to consider big div as base and styling `class="column1"` and `class="column2"`.

My solution for solve this problem is shown here:

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-right:-5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1080px;
}
  
.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  width:50%;
  height:400;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  width:50%;
  height:400;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other on screens that are smaller than 600 px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="row">
<div>
<table class="column1"#ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table class="column2" : #ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```